# ¿Cómo graficar una ecuación implícita como una superficie en 3D en Python?

Tags: python

Estuve buscando formas de graficar superficies pero, ¿qué pasa en el caso de que tenga una ecuación implícita? Es decir, de esta forma `S(x,y,z)= CONSTANTE`

Si tuviera por ejemplo esta ecuación:

```
1/np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2/np.sqrt((x+3)**2 + y**2 + z**2) = 5
```

(Pensando en que es difícil despejar `z`)
¿O hay que jugar con la ecuación hasta que llegue a algo más simple?

Gracias

Comment: Al parecer tu pregunta no es suficientemente clara porque das una ecuación de ejemplo y la solución que te entregué se aplica a ella. Pero al parecer tu pregunta es otra, en es caso debes arreglar tu pregunta o hacer una pregunta más especifica con el caso que te complica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando el dominio de `x` e `y` conocidos. Se puede generar una grilla la cual es llenada con valores resultado de despejar z en aquella función que mencionas.

Es decir, al despejar Z se obtiene:

```
Z = np.sqrt(1/5 - X ** 2 - Y ** 2)
```

Ahora llenamos la matriz de la siguiente forma, y la graficamos con matplotlib:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
# Aqui colocamos el dominio de X e Y y su resolucion, por ejemplo usamos las siguiente:
X = np.arange(0, 0.2, 0.01) # x in [0, 0.2] con resolucion 0.01.
Y = np.arange(0, 0.2, 0.01) # y in [0, 0.2] con resolucion 0.01.
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.sqrt(1/5 - X ** 2 - Y ** 2)  # obtenemos valores de Z.

# Graficar la superficie.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Este codigo está inspirado en [este tutoria](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html)l de matplotlib.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder :) estoy aprendiendo de a poco a graficar superficies y he entendido tu codigo :) pero aún tengo la duda de los casos en que NO pudiera despejar Z de forma fácil :/

Comment: Como que caso? Deberias modificar tu pregunta o hacer una nueva con mas informacion para poder ayudarte. Si resolvi tu pregunta recuerda aceptar mi respuesta, quedo atento a cualquier otro comentario.

Comment: Voy a buscar un ejemplo más claro donde no se pueda despejar Z ya que fue una duda que tuve en el momento y no supe como escribir una ecuación que tuviera este problema, soy nueva en esto de las preguntas jajaj. Perdón las molestias y gracias por tu tiempo :D.